# VBA - UserForm Button should open another Userform, but didn't

Tags: excel, vba, button, userform

I'm quite new in VBA, but I'm trying to create a userforme where the user can can view the information in a spreadsheet through a listbox. In this form, there are buttons with the options 'New,' 'Edit,' and 'Delete' (and 'Close'). However, the focus is on the 'New' button because whenever I try to click on it, it returns the error message 'Subscript out of range'.

[image]

Every time I click on Debug button I send me to this part of code:

```
Private Sub buttonNovo_Click()
    Dim frm As New formNovo
    **frm.Show**
End Sub
```

I tried to change the UserForm name, call it directly (formNovo.show), everything I tried did not solve the problem. Someone has an idea?

Here is the whole code:
modMain:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()

    Dim frm As New formRegistro
    frm.Show
    Set frm = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

modRange:

```
Option Explicit

Public ws As Worksheet

Public Function GetRange() As Range
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro")
    Set GetRange = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set GetRange = GetRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetRange.Rows.Count - 1)
End Function

Public Sub deleterow(ByVal row As Long)
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro")
    ws.Range("A2").Offset(row).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Public Function GetNewID() As Long
    GetNewID = 1 + WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Columns(1))
End Function

Public Function GetTurno() As Variant
    Dim wo As Worksheet
    Set wo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Oculto")
    GetTurno = ws.ListObjects("tbTurno").DataBodyRange.Value
End Function
```

formRegistro:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub buttonClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub buttonNovo_Click()
    Dim frm As New formNovo
    **frm.Show**
End Sub

Private Sub buttonEdit_Click()
    Dim frm As New formAtt
    frm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub buttonDelete_Click()
    Call deleterow(listRegistro.ListIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call AddDataToListBox
End Sub

Public Sub AddDataToListBox()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = GetRange()
    
    With listRegistro
        .RowSource = rg.Address(external:=True)
        .ColumnCount = rg.Columns.Count
        .ColumnWidths = "65,2 pt;97,8 pt;97,8 pt;130,4 pt;130,4 pt;65,2 pt;163 pt"
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

formNovo:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub buttonFechar_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub buttonSalvar_Click()
    
    If MsgBox("Deseja salvar dados?", vbYesNo, "Save Record") = vbYes Then
        'Escrever dados dos controles ao banco de dados
        Call WriteDataToSheet
    
        'Limpar as caixas de texto
        Call EmptyTextBoxes
    
        'Criar um novo ID
        Call CreateID
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub WriteDataToSheet()

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Registro")
    Dim newRow As Integer
    
    With ws
        newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows + 1
        newRow = newRow + 1
        .Cells(newRow, 1).Value = txtID.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 2).Value = txtData.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 3).Value = txtHora.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 4).Value = txtCarga.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 5).Value = txtPlaca.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 6).Value = comboboxTurno.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 7).Value = txtRespons.Value
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub EmptyTextBoxes()
    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
            c.Value = ""
        End If
    Next c
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'criar ID
    Call CreateID
    'iniciar controle
    Call InitializeControls
    
End Sub

Private Sub CreateID()
    Me.txtID.Value = GetNewID()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeControls()
    Me.comboboxTurno.List = GetTurno()
    Me.comboboxTurno.ListIndex = 0
    
End Sub
```

This is the structure of my code:
[image: This is the structure of my code]

Comment: I suspect one of your sheet names is wrong - most likely the `Oculto` one.

Comment: Make sure your VBA error handling settings are set to "break in class module" (*Tools >> Options >> General >> Error Trapping*) or you won't see errors which occur (eg) inside your form code.

Comment: Change your declaration and remove the New keyword: Dim frm As formNovo Subsequently, set the object instance: Set frm = New formNovo. After that show the form

Comment: `GetTurno = ws.ListObjects("tbTurno").DataBodyRange.Value`  Did you mean `wo.ListObjects("tbTurno")` ? If not then what is `wo` for in `GetTurno` ?